# Proving $P(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E _i) \leq \sum_i^\infty P(E _i) $

Tags: probability

I know this works when infinite sequence of events are disjoint. $P(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E _i) = \sum_i^\infty P(E _i) $
The question did not mention whether the sequence of events are disjoint or not. The question was to just that show $P(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E _i) \leq \sum_i^\infty P(E _i) $. So what I thought was if events are not disjoint. Then

$P(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E _i) = \sum_i^\infty P(E _i) - \sum_{i\neq j}^\infty P(E _i \cup E_j ) + ... +(-1)^{n-1}P(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty E_i)$

Hence,

As $\sum_{i\neq j}^\infty P(E _i \cup E_j ) - ... -(-1)^{n-1}P(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty E_i) \geq 0$, it can be proven that

$P(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E _i) \leq \sum_i^\infty P(E _i) $

Comment: What is the question you want us to answer?

Comment: Hint : try playing with the events $F_i=E_i\setminus \bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1} E_j$.

Comment: @P.Quinton I love how three posts were made at almost the exact same time, and not only to all of them propose defining the sets $E_i\setminus\bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1}E_j$, all three of us decided to name the sets $F_i$ :)

Comment: @5xum Yes I was amazed too, $F$ felt really natural as the original ones where $E$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $F_1=E_1,F_2=E_2 \setminus E_1, F_3=E_3 \setminus (E_1\cup E_2),...$. Check that $F_i$'s are disjoint and $\bigcup_iE_i=\bigcup_i F_i$. So $P(\bigcup_iE_i)=P(\bigcup_iF_i)=\sum_i P(F_i)\leq \sum_i P(E_i)$ since $F_i \subseteq E_i$.

Answer (score 3):

Define $F_i$ as follows:

$$F_1 = E_1\\
F_n = E_n\setminus \bigcup_{k=1}^{n-1}E_k$$

Then you should be able to show the following:

1. For each $n$, $P(F_n)\leq P(E_n)$
2. $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty F_i$
3. $F_i$ are disjoint.

and the result should follow from that.

Comment: Thanks a lot :), this proving is much clearer. Perhaps this  is the answer I was looking for!!

Comment: @DavidPark You are welcome. Don't forget to accept an answer if it is what you need.